# How to figure out what is causing CPU usage to spike to 100

Tags: 14.04, cpu-load

For the last few weeks, CPU usage on my computer will spike to nearly 100%, which makes the computer unusable. Sometimes I'm able to switch to a virtual console and issue `sudo shutdown -h now`, but usually the keyboard locks off and I have to do a hard shutdown, which is not good for the hardware. I want to figure out what is causing this so I can hopefully fix it. What is the best way to diagnose this problem?

Edit - `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA` returns:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti XT [Radeon HD 7970/8970 OEM / R9 280X] [1002:6798]
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:3001]
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
```

and `lscpu` returns:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 60
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               800.000
BogoMIPS:              6400.51
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Comment: Type `top` and it will show you the processes running. It'll definitely show whats consuming 100% of your CPU. If it not a important process, you can kill it by typing `k` while running `top` or quit it and `[sudo] kill ProcessID`. eg: `kill 1534` or `sudo kill 1534` if it belongs to root.

Comment: That would be best solution but like I said the desktop freezes up and I usually can't switch to a virtual console.

Comment: Did you try running with Recovery Mode?

Comment: you should add a bit more info about your hardware like the ouputs from: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA` and `lscpu` for example.

Comment: Ok, I put the output of those commands into the question.

Comment: Good question, ideally we need something like `htop` but dumping the CPU usage in a log file, so we can analyse it aftemath.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `htop`.

First, install `htop`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install htop
```

Then, run htop from a terminal:

```
sudo htop
```

`htop` provides many options. The default will filter results by cpu usage so the culprit will appear at the top of the list. You will have the option of killing the process <kbd>F9</kbd> and you can also use strace by pressing <kbd>S</kbd> for the highlighted process.

Answer (score 1):

If you not able to install `htop` because you have a CPU usage of 100%, you could also use the command `top`.

To access all processes start it with `sudo`

```
sudo top
```

Answer (score 1):

From your Ubuntu Software manager, search for 
Task Manager

Install it and it will help you a lot.